# Interagir com Silverlight

Tags: vba, excel-vba, silverlight

Bom a todos, estou desenvolvendo um sistema VBA que busca documentos (.pdf) em um determinado site. Porem me deparei com um problema ao qual nunca tinha visto, o site abre uma aba do IE com um visualizador do Microsoft Silverlight, pois então tenho meu problema, eu não consigo interagir com os controles do Silverlight para poder realizar o download do arquivo. 
Abaixo o código da página vista pelo Inspetor de elementos do IE:

```html
<object width="756" height"768" id="Silverlight" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2">
  <param name="source" value="/ClientBin/VisualizadorTif.xap"></param>
  <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError"></param>
  <param name="background" value="white"></param>
  <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0"></param>
  <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true"></param>
  <param name="windowless" value="true"></param>
  <param name="initParams" value="TipoImagem=,IdContrato=41f37130-588b-4907-adb4-2578b0391f35,NumeroPagina=0"></param>
  <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40624.0">
    <img style="" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181"></img>
  </a>
</object>
```

Será que consigo alguma API ou algo do tipo para poder localizar os campos?

Comment: Você pode ter que utilizar [COM Object](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83996/Silverlight-Interoperability-with-Excel-using-th), creio que está utilizando somente o Web Scrapping de HTML. Ou quando [é um query, traverse em Document Object Model (DOM)](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm). O Silverlight possui um [API em JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645085(v=vs.95).aspx) também.

Comment: Bom dia Daniel, eu fiz uma pesquisa no que você disse para ver se consiga utilizar no meu projeto, mas não consegui achar nada que se assemelhasse ou me desse algum ponto de inicio. Você teria algo que eu pudesse me basear?

Comment: Na verdade agora eu vi que a versão do Silverlight que você está tentando acessar é a SL2, então [não será possível usar o API em JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28241745/7690982). Então fui pesquisar um pouco e para o silverlight você terá que usar algum outro [scraper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5461738/7690982) ou [OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33696501/7690982).

Comment: você conhece algum scraper ou OCR para essa finalidade, eu preciso alguns campos (como imprimir documento ou escolher forma de exibição de um aquivo .pdf).